# Discord.py - Change Channel Permissions

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I am working on a litte discord game right now. The goal is a pokemon fight game.

To do this, a player challenges another player with `?attack <name>`. He then has 30 seconds to accept or decline the challenge.

The attack-command:

```py
@commands.command()
async def attack(self, ctx, member : Union[discord.Member, int] = None):

    with open("attack.json", "r") as f:
        data = json.load(f)

        attack_dict = {
            "player_1": 1,
            "player_2": 1,
            "attack_message": 1,
        }

        data[str(ctx.guild.id)] = attack_dict

        with open("attack.json", "w") as f:
            json.dump(data, f, indent=4)

        valid_reactions = ["✅", "❌"]

        if member == ctx.message.author:

            embed = discord.Embed(
                title="You can not fight yourself!",
                color=0xf7fcfd
            )

            await ctx.send(embed=embed)
            return

        else:

            embed = discord.Embed(
                title=f"{ctx.message.author.name} wants to fight against {member.display_name}",
                description="Click on the check mark to accept the fight!",
                color=0xf7fcfd
            )

            message_fight_player = await ctx.send(embed=embed)
            await message_fight_player.add_reaction("✅")
            await message_fight_player.add_reaction("❌")

            def check(reaction, user):
                return user == member and user != ctx.author and user.bot is False and str(reaction.emoji) in valid_reactions

            try:

                reaction, user = await self.client.wait_for("reaction_add", timeout=30.0, check=check)

                if str(reaction.emoji) == "✅":

                    await message_fight_player.delete()

                    embed = discord.Embed(
                        title=f"{user.display_name} accepted the fight against {ctx.message.author.display_name}! :eyes:",
                        description="Click on the emoji to watch the fight!",
                        color=0xf7fcfd
                    )

                    message_accept_player = await ctx.send(embed=embed)

                    with open("attack.json", "r") as f:
                        data = json.load(f)

                        data[str(ctx.guild.id)]["player_1"] = ctx.message.author.id
                        data[str(ctx.guild.id)]["player_2"] = member.id
                        data[str(ctx.guild.id)]["attack_message"] = message_accept_player.id

                        with open("attack.json", "w") as f:
                            json.dump(data, f, indent=4)

                    await message_accept_player.add_reaction("")
                    await message_accept_player.delete(delay=30)

                    await asyncio.sleep(30)

                    with open("attack.json", "r") as f:
                        data = json.load(f)

                        del data[str(ctx.guild.id)]

                        with open("attack.json", "w") as f:
                            json.dump(data, f, indent=2)

                else:

                    await message_fight_player.delete()

                    with open("attack.json", "r") as f:
                        data = json.load(f)

                        del data[str(ctx.guild.id)]

                        with open("attack.json", "w") as f:
                            json.dump(data, f, indent=2)

                    embed = discord.Embed(
                        title=f"{member.display_name} did not want to fight against {ctx.message.author.name}! :thinking:",
                        color=0xf7fcfd
                    )

                    message_declare_player = await ctx.send(embed=embed)
                    await message_declare_player.delete(delay=10)

            except asyncio.TimeoutError:

                await message_fight_player.delete()

                embed = discord.Embed(
                    title=f"{member.display_name} did not want to fight against {ctx.message.author.name}! :thinking:",
                    color=0xf7fcfd
                )

                message_timeout_player = await ctx.send(embed=embed)
                await message_timeout_player.delete(delay=10)

                with open("attack.json", "r") as f:
                    data = json.load(f)

                    del data[str(ctx.guild.id)]

                    with open("attack.json", "w") as f:
                        json.dump(data, f, indent=2)
```

The command works fine, but now comes the problem, I want to send a message that the fight has been accepted. An emoji () should then be added to this message, if you click on this emoji you should be able to watch the fight.

I've tried that with `on_raw_reaction_add`, but the problem is that it creates a new channel every time someone clicks the emoji.

```py
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_raw_reaction_add(self, payload):

    guild_id = payload.guild_id
    guild = self.client.get_guild(guild_id)

    user_id = payload.user_id
    user = self.client.get_user(user_id)

    channel_id = payload.channel_id
    channel = self.client.get_channel(channel_id)

    message_id = payload.message_id
    emoji = payload.emoji.name

    member = discord.utils.find(lambda m : m.id == payload.user_id, guild.members)

    try:

        with open("attack.json", "r") as jsonData:
            data = json.load(jsonData)

            attack_message_id = data[str(guild_id)]["attack_message"]
            player_1 = data[str(guild_id)]["player_1"]
            player_2 = data[str(guild_id)]["player_2"]

        if message_id == attack_message_id and emoji == "" and user.bot is False:

            message = await channel.fetch_message(message_id)
            await message.remove_reaction("",user)

            category = discord.utils.get(guild.categories, name = "Pokemon")

            if category is None:

                category = await guild.create_category(name="Pokemon")

            player_1_name = self.client.get_user(player_1)
            player_2_name = self.client.get_user(player_2)

            overwrites = {
                guild.default_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=False),
                player_1_name: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True, send_messages=True),
                player_2_name: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True, send_messages=True),
                member: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True, send_messages=False)
            }

            attack_channel = await category.create_text_channel("⁉️ poke-fight", overwrites=overwrites)

    except:

        return
```

So whenever someone clicks on the emoji, I want that person to be added to the channel. Same as `player_1` and `player_2`, but the viewer should have read_messages = True and send_messages = False.

Answer (score 1):

You specifically create a new text channel on all  raw_reaction_add(s) using

`attack_channel = await category.create_text_channel("⁉️ poke-fight", overwrites=overwrites)`

as far as I know discord doesn't have a bultin function to move users to other **text** channels, only **voice** channels using `await move_to(channel)`
Closest you could get is to generate a text link to the channel that the user will have to click:

`await channel.send(f'view fight in {attack_channel.mention}')`

Comment: Thats not what I meant - I want to overwrite the channels persmissions. Like [that](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/771635939700768769/808301927170310155/unknown.png)

Comment: I want to add a person to the channel with ``read_messages=True`` and ``send_messages=False``

Comment: Nevermind I fixed it by myself. Thanks anyways :)